# How to configure Velocity template engine to avoid automatic carriage return in merge result?

Tags: java, velocity

I'm using [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) (1.5) to generate some text using template + data sources.

I need to take care of new lines since merging result is not HTML but text.

I have this kind of template (beanInContext is a matrix of data, like an excel spreadsheet)

```
[begin TPL]
  $beanInContext.prepare("someData");
  $beanInContext.anotherOperation(1234);
  #foreach( $row in $beanInContext.rows() )
    #foreach($data in $row.data())
      $data
    #end
  #end 
[end TPL]
```

And I expect the merging result to be like that:

```
a1 b1 c1
a2 b2 c2
...
```

But I got something like:

```
a1
    b1
  c1
  a2  
    b2  
  c2  
  ...
```

When using the similar template engine [freemarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/), I was using the **<#compress>** directive in order to achieve this kind of formatting.

Someone knows how to configure the velocity engine to avoid this kind of carriage return mess ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Velocity, much like JSP, does not currently provide practical assistance with whitespace management.  It has been much discussed, but no one has ever stepped up to implement the feature.  You will find it much better to use something like JTidy to post-process Velocity output.  Expect to see improvement in whitespace handling for Velocity 2.0, but at this rate, don't expect Velocity 2.0 for a couple years.  Work is slow.

If whitespace control is critical and post-processing is not an option, i would suggest using Freemarker.

And if you must use Velocity, beware that 1.5 has some significant performance issues.  I strongly recommend upgrading to 1.7.

Comment: Small point of clarification: JSP does provide the ability to remove extra whitespace.  Declare the following your web.xml:  
  `<jsp-config>  
    <jsp-property-group>  
      <description>  
        Trims generated whitespace from JSPs  
      </description>  
      <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>  
      <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>  
    </jsp-property-group>  
  </jsp-config>`

Answer (score 2):

I may not have this exactly right, yet here's the basic trick of how to do it:

```
> [begin TPL]
> $beanInContext.prepare("someData");
> $beanInContext.anotherOperation(1234);
> #foreach( $row in $beanInContext.rows() )
> #**##foreach($data in $row.data())##
> #*    *#$data##
> #**##end##
> #end 
> [end TPL]
```

Comment: Thanks WhiteFang34. I have seen a post on a mailing list with this kind of answer, but I was expecting something less messy and ugly :)